# Use 1d boolean index to select out of 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Sometimes I'll have an `ND` array out of which I need to select data, but the data criterion has only `M < N` dimensions. Take for example

```
## generate some matrix
test = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
## some condition based on first-dimension only
selectMe = np.array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Now, I would like to do

```
test[selectMe[:, None]]
```

but that leads to an IndexError:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

Naturally, if I repeat the boolean index on the second dimension, everything works -- the following is the expected output:

```
test[np.repeat(selectMe[:, None], 3, axis=1)]
Out[41]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

However, this is quite inefficient. What's the natural way of achieving this with `numpy` without having to repeat the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can use ellipsis (`...`) to cover unfiltered dimensions:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.arange(10000).reshape((100, 100))

# condition
selectMe = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100).astype(bool)

assert (test[selectMe, ...].ravel() == test[np.repeat(selectMe[:, None], 100, axis=1)]).all()

%timeit test[selectMe, ...].ravel()                       # 11.6 µs
%timeit test[np.repeat(selectMe[:, None], 100, axis=1)]   # 103 µs
```