# 2d boolean selection in 3d matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[In a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718603/use-1d-boolean-index-to-select-out-of-2d-array) I learned that if I have an array of shape `MxMxN`, and I want to select based on a boolean matrix of shape `MxM`, I can simply do

```
data[select, ...]
```

and be done with it. Unfortunately, now I have my data in a different order:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(36).reshape((3, 4, 3))
select = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=9).reshape((3, 3)).astype(bool)
```

For each element in `data` indexed `i0, i1, i2`, it should be selected, if `select[i0, i2] == True`.

How can I proceed with my selection without having to do something inefficient like

```
data.flatten()[np.repeat(select[:, None, :], 4, axis=1).flatten()]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to simply use `np.broadcast_to` to broadcast without actual replication and use that broadcasted mask directly for masking required elements -

```
mask = np.broadcast_to(select[:,None,:], data.shape)
out = data[mask]
```

Another way and probably faster one would be to get the indices and then index with those. The elements thus obtained would be ordered by `axis=1`. The implementation would look something like this -

```
idx = np.argwhere(select)
out = data[idx[:,0], :, idx[:,1]]
```